# gorm query by in condition with pq.Array

Tags: grails-orm

Gorm query with IN condtion is not working with pq.Array

these are my models:

```
Task struct {
        Name      string
        Status    TaskStatus
        Details   string
        Deadline  time.Time
        Files     pq.StringArray `gorm:"type:text[]"`       
        gorm.Model
    }
```

```
File struct {
        ID   uuid.UUID `gorm:"primarykey"`
        Name string
        Ext  string
        Data []byte
    }
```

when i search files like this:

```
db.Where("id IN ?", task.Files).Find(&files)
```

is converting to  `SELECT * FROM files WHERE id IN '{"cb71f854-71fc-4849-9783-71cf8f8e4214"}'`this query and then it is not working. Any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Gorm expects a slice of strings, not a `pq.StringArray`

It's also a more efficient SQL query to turn the query around into:

```
db.Where(&File{Task: task}).Find(&files)
```